# Null-space of skew-centrosymmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $J$ be the matrix with ones on the bottom-left to top-right diagonal and zeros elsewhere (i.e. the identity matrix with reversed columns). A matrix $A$ is skew-centrosymmetric if
$$
JAJ = -A.
$$
Assume that $A$ is real and skew-centrosymmetric and has the additional properties
$$
A \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0} \\
A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{1},
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector whose elements are all 1, and $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, \dots, x_n)^T$ is a given vector with the properties $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_{n-1} < x_n$ and $J \mathbf{x} = - \mathbf{x}$.

**Question:** Is $\mathbf{1}$ the only non-trivial vector in the null-space of $A$? (Constant multiples of $\mathbf{1}$ of course works but I'm not interested in these.) Can a counterexample be constructed?

**Example:** The simplest example is probably
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 \\
1/2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here, $A$ is nil-potent and $\mathbf{1}$ is the only eigenvector.

I have played around a bit with matrices of dimension $n=2,3$ and 4 without finding a counterexample. There are plenty of matrices arising from discretising ODEs and PDEs that have the above listed properties and with only $\mathbf{1}$ in the null-space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where the matrix $A$ is a $3 \times 3 $ matrix and more specifically:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac 12 & 0 & \frac 12 \\ -\frac 12 & 0 & \frac 12 \\ -\frac 12 & 0 & \frac 12 \end{bmatrix}.$$

- We can easily see that $A\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 0.$
- Also, we can consider the vector $\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\1 \end{bmatrix},$ satisfying the condition $x_1 < x_2 < x_3.$ We can verify that $J\mathbf x = -\mathbf x$ and $A\mathbf x = \mathbf 1$.
- Also, we can see that $JAJ = - A$.

But $\dim\operatorname{null} A = 2,$ with $$\operatorname{null}A = \left\{\;\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} ,\; \begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \\0  \end{bmatrix} \;\right\}.$$